# Validate that a combination of cells are unique in a row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel sheet where 3 columns (A, B, and C) form a unique identifier for each row, but the values in the columns are not unique. For example:

```
   ABC    REF   001
   ABC    REF   002
   ABC    REF   003
   ABC    DOC   001
   ABC    DOC   002
   ABC    DOC   003
```

The above rows are valid, because no row has the same combination of values (e.g. there are no two rows with "ABC REF002" even those there are duplicates of columns B and C)

How can I add an Excel validation such that if the user enters a combination of values in columns A, B, and C that matches the combination of another row, a validation error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim I As Long, st As String, J As Long, k As Long
    Dim CH As String

    If Intersect(Range("A:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    CH = Chr(1)
    I = Target.Row
    J = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    st = Cells(I, 1).Text & CH & Cells(I, 2).Text & CH & Cells(I, 3).Text

    For k = 1 To J
        If k <> I Then
            stk = Cells(k, 1).Text & CH & Cells(k, 2).Text & CH & Cells(k, 3).Text
            If st = stk Then
                MsgBox "Combination already in use:" & vbCrLf & stk
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next k

End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: This macro gives me the following error: "Unable to get the Text property of the Range class". This error occurs on the line with the `st` declaration This is with Excel 2007

Comment: Very strange..............I don't see this error.

Comment: It looks to have been related to the data format in the cells I was testing. Changing all of the columns to text fixed the problem.

Comment: Good job debugging!

Comment: @Gary : Any idea of why a 'RunTIme Error : 1007 -  Applicatiobn Defined or Object Defined Error' throws? I just change the If conditon only as my column count is more. Therefore as 'Intersect(Range("B:F"), Target)'. Will you be able to assist me ?

Comment: @hirosht  this code is specific to **A:C** ............. to change to **B:F** you must change all the *Cells()* calls.............